# Accessing anonymous share link from SharePoint in C# code (and Postman) results in 403

Tags: sharepoint, http-status-code-403, webclient

I'm tasked with emailing out some files from our SharePoint site (don't know version or hosting, but can find out).  As a quick test, I accessed one of the files, created an "Anyone with the link can view" link, and plunked it into the code.  This code returns a 403.

Doing the same thing with a Dropbox link works as expected.  I've verified the SP file can be accessed outside of our network, from my phone, on a personal laptop, etc, so it is in fact anonymous.  Clearly I'm missing a magical header or something.  I suspected redirects, but after following them, I still get 403.

The reason I need the shared link is that we have an "EmailService" that wants a URL for any attachments.  It's actually that code which is failing, but I can reproduce locally.

This is what the service is doing:

```
private static void Download()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var data = webClient.DownloadData("https://oursharepointaddy.com/:i:/s/blah/funkyShareurlhere?e=somestuffhere&download=1");
    }
```

When using F12 in Chrome, I noticed a redirect so I handled that in the code below.  It happily follows the 302, then BOOM, 403.

```
 private static void DownloadII()
    {
        var uri = $"https://oursharepointaddy.com/:i:/s/blah/funkyShareurlhere?e=somestuffhere&download=1";

        while (true)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler {AllowAutoRedirect = false};
            var response = new HttpClient(handler).SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var statusCode = (int) response.StatusCode;

            if (statusCode >= 300 && statusCode <= 399)
            {
                var redirectUri = response.Headers.Location;
                if (!redirectUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                {
                    redirectUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + redirectUri);
                }

                uri = redirectUri.AbsoluteUri;
                continue;
            }

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also get a 403 through Postman.  Browsers seem to be fine.  Even incognito mode in Chrome... no problem.
I've tried various headers (UserAgent and some others I spied in Chrome), added and removed the `download=1`.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Small update: If I capture the redirect url and put it in Postman, it's successful.  Using the redirect URL in code still fails.  If I open an incognito Chrome window, paste in the original URL it's successful, but the address bar contains the redirect url.  If I copy that new URL, close the window and open a new incognito window and paste in that new URL, it prompts me to sign in.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be cookies.  Didn't need the redirection following loop either. Just tell the `HttpClientHander` to `UseCookies = true`.

```
private static void DownloadIV()
    {
        var uri = "https://oursharepointaddy.com/:i:/s/blah/funkyShareurlhere?e=somestuffhere&download=1";
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = true, UseCookies = true };

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);

        var response = new HttpClient(handler).SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var data = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            using (var stm = File.Create("downloaded.xlsx"))
            {
                data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                data.CopyTo(stm);
            }
        }
    }
```

For completeness, this is how my original code could look to also work as expected:

```
private static void DownloadII()
{
    var uri = $"https://oursharepointaddy.com/:i:/s/blah/funkyShareurlhere?e=somestuffhere&download=1";
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler {AllowAutoRedirect = false, UseCookies = true};
    while (true)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
        var response = new HttpClient(handler).SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var statusCode = (int) response.StatusCode;

        if (statusCode >= 300 && statusCode <= 399)
        {
            var redirectUri = response.Headers.Location;
            if (!redirectUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
            {
                redirectUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + redirectUri);
            }

            uri = redirectUri.AbsoluteUri;
            continue;
        }

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var data = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```